# PHP GZip and Server Sent Event Streams

Tags: php, gzip, server-sent-events

I'm writing a [server sent event](http://www.w3.org/TR/eventsource/) stream in PHP and I receive the error:

> "failed to flush buffer zlib output compression"

This I believe is due to trying to flush the gzipped output.

Here's my PHP code:

```
header ("Content-Type: text/event-stream\n\n");
header ("Cache-Control: no-cache");

echo "data: {$json}";
echo "\n\n";

ob_flush(); // ERROR HERE
flush();
```

My question is what is the best way to get this working - ideally without disabling gzip in apache - can it be turned off in PHP?

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression')){
    ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use zlib output compression along ob_ output handler.  See the php docs on zlib.output_compression, it states it multiple times.

If found out that the easiest way to enable output compression in php is to just do this:

```
ini_set("zlib.output_compression", 1);
ini_set("zlib.output_compression_level", 9);
```

And loose all the ob_* stuff.   Now when a client requests a page with a header like :

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

zlib will gzip your response body for you AND it will set this for you in the response:

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

I spent hours of my life on this before realising how simple it is with those 2 lines.  and don't use any flush at all implicitely